# Что такое микро и макрозадачи в JS?

Tags: javascript

Объясните , если можно, по простому что такое микро- и макрозадачи, а то мало информации на эту тему. Спасибо!

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-loop

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIZs5tH-HGQ